# Run an app on configured virtual device

Tags: android, image-processing, virtual-device-manager

I have developed an app of image processing. In which app is working fine in Android 6.0 and above version but it crashes below 6.0 android version especially in specific devices as well. I want to run my app in the configured virtual device with below specification.

**OS : Android 5.1.1

Device : OPPO A37f**

Please suggest me an online platform for the run and trace my issue. I do not want to run the app in Genymotion.

Comment: You can use Firebase Test Lab. Why not the official emulator? It's performance is equal to Genymotion now

Comment: @Chisko : For emulator testing, I have to download its image file which is a lengthy process. Thank you for suggestion